# Store Hours field in Matrix

Tags: matrix

I'm using the Store Hours plugin inside of a Matrix field along with a text input field. The global is called specialHours and the matrix has the same name.

I access the text input like this which works:

```
{% for block in specialHours.specialHours %}

<h2>{{ block.heading }}</h2>

{% endfor %}
```

What I don't understand is how to loop through the store hours days.  This is not working:

```
{% for day in block.specialHours %}
<tr><td> <strong>{{ day.name }}</strong> </td><td>{% if day.isBlank %}
                Closed
            {% else %}
                {{ day.open|time('ga') }} - {{ day.close|time('ga') }}
            {% endif %}</td></tr>
```

Any ideas?  Thank you!

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas on this?  Need to figure out if store hours is going to work inside a Matrix field. Thanks!

Comment: Last try.  Anyone have any ideas?